# How to remove special characters from filenames conforming to S3?

Tags: regex, amazon-s3, sed

I'm attempting to rename an entire filesystem in order to conform to S3 naming guidelines. This is a requirement for using Amazon's snowball unit.

There are a LOT of characters to replace, and I understand each of them has its own special way of escaping. I have to keep some of them, such as - and

So far I've attempted several sed tricks but it's always messy.

Each character seems to have its own unique way of escaping.

Are there better ways to do this?

This is what I got so far:

```
    #!bin/bash
    for f in "($find ./ -type f)"; do
     newName=`sed 's/[!@?:#$%^&*()]/_/g' << '$f'``
    done
```

Comment: I'd write a python dict that blindly replaces strings in filenames till it's done. Be sure to make backups!

Answer (score 0):

This would be a lot easier to do in `tr`, using negation/complement.  Basically, list all the valid characters you want to allow your files to have, and tell `tr` to replace anything else with your replacement character `_`:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    for filename in "($find ./ -type f)"; do
       newName=`echo -n ${filename} | tr -c 'A-Za-z0-9_.' '_'`
    done
```

In the above example, you'd allow all printable uppercase and lowercase letters, numbers, `_` and `.`.  Add any other characters you want to allow to the list.

Also, just for reference, I found this link that details all the characters you should avoid for S3 object names: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html